# 2d textures from canvas isn't updating "fast enough" for Three.js?

Tags: canvas, three.js

I'm trying to create a "dynamic texture", using an off-screen canvas. This is my test-case code: https://dpaste.de/EvuZ

**Expected results** was to instantiate 2 THREE.Mesh objects, with 2 different textures.

**Actual results** both mesh objects have the same texture for some reason. However, if I add a setTimeout at line 50, and do the same thing, it works.

There's something fundamental I'm missing here because I can't get this to work. Any ideas?

Using three.js#r64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MyObject` is not doing what you think it's doing.

You are self-invoking it which means `MyObject` only consist of the *new* object/function you are returning inside it. You are basically overriding its parent context but since there is a valid reference to the parent canvas the first time this will be used also for the next calls.

There is no need to over-complicate these objects. Try something like this instead:

```
var MyObject = function(data) {

    var _canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    _canvas.width = 200;
    _canvas.height = 200;

    var _context = _canvas.getContext('2d');
    _context.font = 'bold 20px Helvetica';
    _context.lineWidth = 1;
    _context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
    _context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
    _context.clearRect(0, 0, _canvas.width, _canvas.height);
    _context.strokeText('n:' + data, 2, 30);

    var _geometry = {
        front: new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 200)
    };

    var texture = new THREE.Texture(_canvas);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture
    });

    /// expose properties this way
    this.data = data;
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(_geometry.front, material);

    return this;
};
```

Now you can see in [this simple test](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/ZbJTa/) that you are working on two different instances (disclaimer: I did not set up fiddle to test the other aspects - if it still fails consider set up a fiddle for us).

Now the reference to canvas, context etc. will be valid for each instance. If you plan to use several of these instances you could look into using prototypes.

Comment: Alright, thanks. So basically I over-complicated my object. So basically I'm required to create a new canvas and a new context for each texture I want to draw? Considering I'm planing to make multiple textures this way, isn't that quite resource intensive?

Comment: @iwantoski it will require more resources to store different images in memory but depending on the size of the canvases it's not necessary it will have significant impact on the system. In your example here the raw memory is 200 x 200 x 4 bytes or 156 kb.